# SparkR. Convert UTC to local time for all observations, multiple timezones

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am new to SparkR, learning as I go, and on version 2.2.0 - SNAPSHOT. I have a SparkDataFrame with one column of UTC timestamps, one column of time zones. For example:

```
mydates<- c("2012-12-22 14:23:05", "2015-01-19 16:37:42", "2017-03-02 08:22:55")
mytimeZones<- c("America/Chicago", "America/New_York", "Pacific/Galapagos")
dfr<- data.frame(date=mydates, timezone=mytimeZones)

dfs<- SparkR::createDataFrame(dfr)
```

What I would like to do is make a column of local times for each observation in my dataset. I saw that the `from_utc_timestamp()` function takes in a column of timestamps and a string representing the desired timezone conversion. My problem is that I have columns of both. Given this, I am wondering what the workflow would need to be, and if someone with more experience with SparkR might be willing to shed insight into how I can tackle this problem? At the moment, I have tried things like this:

```
dftest<- withColumn(dfs, "LocalTime", 
  SparkR:::foreach(dfs, function(x){from_utc_timestamp(y=x$date, x=x$timezone)})
)
```

But with no success. I'm hoping someone out there has tackled this problem in SparkR and could help me. Thanks for your time. 
Kind Regards,
 Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `selectExpr`:

```
selectExpr(dfs, "*", "from_utc_timestamp(date, timezone) AS LocalTime")
```

or `expr`:

```
withColumn(dfs, "LocalTime", expr("from_utc_timestamp(date, timezone)"))
```

In a simpler case, where timezone is a constant string calling `from_utc_timestamp` directly would do the trick:

```
withColumn(dfs, "LocalTime", 
  from_utc_timestamp(column("date"), "America/New_York")
```

Unfortunately there is no `from_utc_timestamp` with signature `(Column, Column) => Column`, hence the SQL-ish solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted/needed. Thank you very much. --nate